# How to track down ECONNREFUSED in a Node.js TCP server?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have written a TCP server using [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode). Basically, everything works fine.

Now I have also created some unit tests, and one of them fails with `ECONNREFUSED`.

What's strange about this is that

- the code being tested works great when run outside the unit test, inside the application,
- the code being tested works if I comment out the test before the failing test.

So obviously there seems to be an interdependency between two tests. Both work alone, but not together with each other.

The problem is that I get a quite useless error message:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:768:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:759:19)
```

It's nice to see that it's an `ECONNREFUSED` error, but how do I figure out what is causing the issue?

As there are lots of callbacks who incorporate anonymous functions it is not *that* easy to figure out which line causes the issues :-(.

Any ideas / hints?

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` usually means that the process that you are trying to connect to is actually not running. Perhaps you started the server and didn't wait long enough for it to start running? Or maybe the server was unable to listen on the port you are connecting to because that port was already in use (likely by a previous instance of that same server).

Comment: Does the test create a new instance of the server? Or do both tests use the same instance of the server that remains running throughout them?

Comment: Each test creates a new instance of the server, binds it to port 3000 and closes the server before finishing. This works in a perfect way (there is even a test for that ;-)). Regarding the issue of not waiting long enough: I'm using a callback that is called by the `listen` function, hence the server should be up and running.

Comment: You confirmed that `bind`/`listen` succeed in the server?

Comment: Yes. And as it works in all other tests (28 at the moment) and they are all using the same structure, I can not imagine that this should be the problem. I just tested it once again: Both tests work, if you comment one of them out. As soon as they are both there, the second one fails with `ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: I just found the error ... in test number one I start two TCP servers who interact with each other. When I close #1, #2 fails with `ECONNREFUSED` as #1 is gone. So it's not the second test that fails, it's the first one, but the test framework displays the error in a wrong way. As all remaining tests are *VERY* fast, they rush through before the problem exists if I comment out test #2.

Comment: I don't think anyone not familiar with the details ever would have guessed that. Glad you found it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time anyway :-). Sometimes it's already enough to explain the problem to someone else to better understand it.

Comment: That is one task for which I am fully qualified. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by myself, see the comments above.